# Python Program stuck on decoding bytes

Tags: python

I'm trying to do a local remote access to another computer using websocket and I need to transform a subprocess.check_output into a string to send it over ws but when I'm trying to decode using the byte.decode method, the program just stays here (it prints 1, res but not rep) and I don't know why

```py
def on_message(wsapp, msg):
    print(msg)
    req = json.loads(msg)
    print(1)
    res = subprocess.check_output(req["command"], shell=True)
    print(res)
    decRes = res.decode(errors='ignore')
    rep = {"command": req["command"], 'answer': decRes, "sendOutput": req['returnOutput']}
    print(rep)
    ws.send(json.dumps(rep))
```

output for command "dir" :

```
{"command": "dir", "sendOutput": true}
1
b" Le volume dans le lecteur F s'appelle HDD2\r\n Le num\x82ro de s\x82rie du volume est FE33-CF17\r\n\r\n R\x82pertoire de F:\\Python\\test\r\n\r\n05/10/2021  19:13    <DIR>          .\r\n05/10/2021  19:13    <DIR>          ..\r\n05/10/2021  18:57    <DIR>          .idea\r\n05/10/2021  19:13               524 client.py\r\n28/09/2021  20:54    <DIR>          clients\r\n05/10/2021  19:00               798 for_me.py\r\n28/09/2021  20:47             1\xff989 main.py\r\n               3 fichier(s)            3\xff311 octets\r\n               4 R\x82p(s)  765\xff958\xff098\xff944 octets libres\r\n"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decoding will use UTF-8 (or whatever `sys.getdefaultencoding()` returns), but your bytes are not UTF-8 encoded.  Use instead:

```
decRes = res.decode("cp850")
```

The content looks like French in [Code Page 850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850):

```
>>> print(b.decode("cp850"))
 Le volume dans le lecteur F s'appelle HDD2
 Le numéro de série du volume est FE33-CF17

 Répertoire de F:\Python\test

05/10/2021  19:13    <DIR>          .
05/10/2021  19:13    <DIR>          ..
05/10/2021  18:57    <DIR>          .idea
05/10/2021  19:13               524 client.py
28/09/2021  20:54    <DIR>          clients
05/10/2021  19:00               798 for_me.py
28/09/2021  20:47             1 989 main.py
               3 fichier(s)            3 311 octets
               4 Rép(s)  765 958 098 944 octets libres
```

This fixes the issue of the corrupted decoding, but that would not be the cause of the program crashing or getting "stuck" as the question title suggests, because using `res.decode(errors='ignore')` will ignore decoding errors. Since you mentioned the code prints `res` but does not print `rep`, the error must be on the only other line between them:

```
print(res)
decRes = res.decode(errors='ignore')
rep = {"command": req["command"], 'answer': decRes, "sendOutput": req['returnOutput']}
print(rep)
```

The only way the line `rep = ...` can possibly fail is if the key "returnOutput" was not present in `req`. It can not be the case that the key "command" missing, or that `req` isn't a dict, since `req["command"]` has been successfully indexed a few lines earlier. So change this line to:

```
rep = {
    "command": req["command"],
    "answer": decRes,
    "sendOutput": req.get("returnOutput"),
}
```

Comment: The problem is that it works in the console (even with the wrong encoding, it's okay) but not in the program

Comment: As @Hitobat said, the problem was from the dict, but thanks, i was wondering how to decode this

Comment: @Moréo Expanded the answer.